# How Set Open and Close of specific div block only using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please check this Link https://jsfiddle.net/bhargavjoshi/sL8f6bkr/3/

I am trying to setup Open a block by clicking continue reading and closing the block by clicking show less.

now it's normally working fine but the issue is when I am opening two blocks for eg. 1 and 2 point are open and If am clicking show less of point no 1 then it will close first block but also change the status of show less to continue reading of block 2.

so how can I set that by clicking show less it will close only specific that block only.

```
jQuery(".show-slide-wrp").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var slidindWrp = jQuery(this).data("slide");
    console.log(slidindWrp);
    jQuery(slidindWrp).slideDown();
    jQuery(this).hide();
});


jQuery(".hide-slide-wrp").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var closeDiv = $this.closest(".sliding-wrp");
    jQuery(".show-slide-wrp").show();
    closeDiv.slideUp();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: closeDiv.offset().top - 300
    }, 500);

});

// scoll by id
jQuery(".contenttable a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var getScrollId = $this.attr("href");  
    console.log(getScrollId);
   jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(getScrollId).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Yes it's down : https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/jsfiddle.net

Comment: I know may jsfiddle has some kind of issue. please check here : https://codepen.io/bhargavjoshi/pen/RwwMPEG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
    jQuery(".hide-slide-wrp").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var closeDiv = $this.closest(".sliding-wrp");
    jQuery(".show-slide-wrp").show(); // You show all "Keep reading" occurences
    closeDiv.slideUp();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: closeDiv.offset().top - 300
    }, 500);

});
//you could put a data-target on theses elements :
<div class="hide-slide-wrp" data-target=".sliding7"><a>Show less</a></div>
```

edited : I made a pen : in order not to manually add attributes to your html like a data-target as your page looks like static html, I add a data-target to the "show less" link when the user click on the "keep reading" link. then when I click on the "Show less" link I know which "keep reading" link to hide
do you see what I mean ?

First : when you click on "Keep readin" add a data-target attribute to the right closing tag :

```
 var $closingTag = $(this).closest(".benefixbox").find(".hide-slide-wrp");
```

Second : when you click on the closing tag : hide the "Keep reading" tag :

```
var dataTarget = $(this).data("target");// here is my target : keep reading
    jQuery("[data-slide='"+dataTarget+"']").show(); // we show the link keep reading again because we know what its data-slide is
```

Comment: can you explain me? like i know problem is there because that is the part code which actually working for closing the block div

Comment: The problem i see is that when you click on a link "show less" it shows every link "Keep reading" on the page. By adding a data-target you will know which tag to hide

Comment: i actually dont understand means how to target and set for closing specific div?

Comment: Wait i have a bug ! :-( your need to find back the link "Keep reading" by finding its data-slide property !